# Wait until query is complete?

Tags: vba, excel

I have macro that pulls data from website in CSV format and puts it in Sheet1 A1. Now I want to convert the data text to columns. If I run this pull data macro and then separately the text to columns macro it works fine. If I do it in one macro it does not work since it takes some time to pull the data and the text to column code executes before the data pulling is finished.

How do I make the macro wait until my data pull is complete and then do text to columns?

```
Option Explicit

Sub PPR()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim stt As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set tgt = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set stt = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    tgt.Cells.ClearContents
    Dim pID As String
    Dim sType As String
    Dim sDateInt As String
    Dim sHourInt As String
    Dim sMinuteInt As String
    Dim eDateInt As String
    Dim eHourInt As String
    Dim eMinuteInt As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim url1 As String
    Dim url2 As String
    Dim url3 As String
    Dim url4 As String
    Dim url5 As String
    Dim url6 As String
    Dim url7 As String
    Dim url8 As String

'Variables
    pID = stt.Range("B1")
    sType = stt.Range("B2")
    sDateInt = Format(Now, "YYYY/MM/DD")
    sHourInt = stt.Range("B4")
    sMinuteInt = stt.Range("C4")
    eDateInt = Format(Now, "YYYY/MM/DD")
    eHourInt = stt.Range("B5")
    eMinuteInt = stt.Range("C5")

    url1 = "URL;https://blabla.com/reports/blabla?reportFormat=CSV&blabla=bla"
    url2 = url1 & "&blabla=" & pID
    url3 = url2 & "&maxIntradayDays=1&spanType=" & sType
    url4 = url3 & "&startDateIntraday=" & sDateInt
    url5 = url4 & "&startHourIntraday=" & sHourInt
    url6 = url5 & "&startMinuteIntraday=" & sMinuteInt
    url7 = url6 & "&endDateIntraday=" & eDateInt
    url8 = url7 & "&endHourIntraday=" & eHourInt
    url = url8 & "&endMinuteIntraday=" & eMinuteInt

    With tgt.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        url, _
        Destination:=tgt.Range("A1"))
        .Refresh
    End With

    tgt.Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
    ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not just check the destination range after your query and wait until that is populated? Also, you don't need to activate the sheet or `.Select` a range. It actually serves no purpose. You've already done early binding, just use `tgt`

Comment: How would I go about this? Also I tried tgt.TextToColumns and it doesn't work.

Comment: Presuming that your range has no value to start with (i.e. A1 has no value), you could try something like `Len(Trim(tgt.Range("A1").Value)) = 0 Then`.. now you can use the explicit wait (i.e. `Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,5)`.. copied form @QHarr). Saying that, QHarr is probably on the right track

Comment: Its company internal website not accessible to public...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a DoEvents in to yield control to the OS

```
DoEvents

With tgt.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        url, _
        Destination:=tgt.Range("A1"))
        .Refresh
End With
```

And/Or:

Use an explicit wait

```
With tgt.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        url, _
        Destination:=tgt.Range("A1"))
        .Refresh
End With

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,5) '<== Adjust number of seconds
```

Or (the list goes embarassingly on), try waiting for a cell to become populated as suggested by @zac.

```
With tgt.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        url, _
        Destination:=tgt.Range("A1"))
        .Refresh
End With

Dim t As Date
t = Timer

Do
    DoEvents
    If Timer - t = 100 Then Exit Do '<==To avoid infinite loop
Loop While IsEmpty(tgt.Range("A2"))
```

Comment: I already tried Doevents and it doesn't work. Also the explicit also doesn't work.

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? If you put a long enough explicit wait after the query, then provided the query runs the data will be there.

Comment: The query takes less than 5 seconds normally. I just tried Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30) and it somehow delays the query. There is External data: getting data... for 30 sec then still no text to columns.

Comment: Is there a cell that is not populated at the start that is expected to be populated after the query is run? A cell in the same column near the top? e.g. A2?

Comment: @QHarr, does the `DoEvents` need to be after the query?

Comment: Yes. I use tgt.Cells.ClearContents at the start so A2 should be empty.

Comment: @Zac I am never clear on that tbh. I assumed you say it once and it carries on applying. I assumed that as Excel is single threaded it cannot send a worker off to do something else but I don't know the internals. I guess it could decide to handle in a different ordering?  Mandmi you can try moving it.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for that. Any suggestions for modifying the above then? I assumed you want the query to complete then move on which is why I put the DoEvents before that.

Comment: I tried it and in A1 there is "ExternalData_59: Getting Data ..." and on status bar is says running background query... It is stuck like this until I manually fill A2 and the it fills with the csv data :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm sometimes using OLEDBConnections to refresh data from DB. 
It acts same as yours when `backgroundquery` isn't set (it continues to run code without waiting for query end)

Code is something like this

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnName").OLEDBConnection
   .BackgroundQuery = False
   .CommandText = "Select something"
   .CommandType = xlCmdSql
   .Connection = "connection string"
   .Refresh
End With
```

Try to look for `.backgroundquery` parameter for your connection

Answer (score 1):

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Instead of

```
.Refresh
```

fixed this.